# Create a histogram of the lengths of words

Tags: beginner, c, ascii-art, data-visualization

I am reading through K&R C 2nd Edition, and I am on exercise 1-13. The exercise is to *write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in
its input.* I wrote a program that successfully does this; however, after looking at the program, I noticed that it was somewhat messy, and I'm sure that there is a better way to implement it. I'm looking for some tips as to how I can improve programs like this in the future.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0
#define MAXVAL 11

int main(){
    int i, j, c, state;
    int wordLengths[MAXVAL];
    int currentWord = 0;
    int greaterThanMax = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < MAXVAL; i++){
        wordLengths[i] = 0; 
    }

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        ++currentWord;  
        state = IN;
        if(c == '\n' || c == ' ' || c == '\t'){
            state = OUT;    
            --currentWord;
        }   
        if(state == OUT){
            if(currentWord < MAXVAL){
                ++wordLengths[currentWord];
            }
            else{
                ++greaterThanMax;   
            }
            currentWord = 0;
        } 
    }
    for(i = 1; i < MAXVAL; i++){
        printf("%d letter(s): ", i);
        for(j = 0; j <= wordLengths[i] - 1; j++){
            putchar('=');   
        }   
        putchar('\n');
    }
    printf(">%d: ", MAXVAL - 1);
    for(i = 0; i < greaterThanMax; i++){
        putchar('=');   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Do not be shy on horizontal spacing. Add space after the keywords (e.g. `while (`, or `if (`). Insert space into `){`.

  If you place an opening curly bracket on the same line as `if`, be consistent with `else`:

  ```
    if () {
        ....
    } else {
        ....
    }
  ```
- `currentWord` actually refers to the current word *length*. Consider renaming.
- Instead of testing `state == OUT`, consider adding a word immediately, as soon as state become `OUT`:

  ```
      if (c == '\n' || c == ' ' || c == '\t') {
          if (currentWordLength < MAXVAL) {
              ++wordLengths[currentWordLength - 1]; {
          } else {
              ++greaterThanMax;
          }
          currentWord = 0;
      }
  ```

  Notice that with this approach you don't need to maintain state explicitly.
- Every output line, except last one, starts with a single-digit number, but the last one starts with 10, and looks unaligned. Consider printing letter count with `"%2d"`.
- The greater-than-max line doesn't end with a newline. Some shells (like `cmd.exe`) automatically add a newline to the last output. Unixish shells do not. On my system an output looks like

  ```
  ....
  >10: ==vnp>
  ```

  Even on Windows, try to redirect your output into a file.

  It is usually a good idea to terminate the output with a newline.